# loop execute command while port/connection is closed to maintain SSH tumnel

Tags: android, bash, shell, ssh, init.d

I am trying to write a script that will maintain a ssh tunnel for me in background on an android device using init.d.

```
#!/system/xbin/bash

. /system/etc/sshd.conf

while ! ping -c1 www.google.com &>/dev/null; do:; 
done

ssh -T -K 120 -i "$KEYFILE" -R "$REVPORT":localhost:"$PORT "$REMUSER"@"$REMSERV" -p "$REMSERVPORT" -y
```

What I need is a loop that will continuously check every X secs if there is an active connection to $REMSERV/$REMSERVPORT if it closes run the ssh line & continue checking. keeping in mind I have a limited set of CLI tools at my disposal. I was looking into autossh instead but I couldn't find a compiled binary for my platform. I am wondering if netstat could help with this? I appreciate ANY feedback & explanations on how code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I accomplished creating my persistent ssh tunnel using init.d & a bash script on android.

```
#!/system/xbin/bash

. /system/etc/sshd.conf

until ssh -N -g -T -K 180 -i "$KEYFILE" -R "$REVPORT":localhost:"$PORT" "$REMUSER"@"$REMSERV" -p "$REMSERVPORT" -y 
do
sleep 1; ssh -T -i "$KEYFILE" "$REMUSER"@"$REMSERV" -p "$REMSERVPORT" -y ssh localhost -p "$REVPORT"
done
```

The first line of script directs to my "config" file which gets written to by a script that uses sed & read. On loop the first part sets up the reverse ssh tunnel using variables from the .conf file & continues to do so until return 0. The second part connects to ssh server and runs ssh command to free up the stuck port caused by dropped connection.

Answer (score 2):

I think you simply need to run in loop your ssh command *(or I missed something)*.

`until ssh`*`<the-options>`*
`do
  sleep 1
done`

While ssh exits with error, this loop will sleep 1 second then retry.
*(I always prefer/use `until foo` instead of `while ! foo`, but both work)*

Comment: So with your loop the SSH command wont keep executing & if the connection drops it will reconnect?

Comment: @Geofferey `until` (as `while`) waits for the return value of the command when you use `until foo bar` (foo:command, bar:parameter). If `foo` returns 0, `while` does the do-done section then relaunch the command `foo` and so on. It is exactly the opposite with `until` (running the do-done then relaunching the command, while the command does not return 0). `ssh` (as any other command) returns an exit code **at its end**; it does not return 0 when connection fails (for example).

Comment: Okay I understand now :) one problem tho. When the connection drops my router keeps the reverse port open and the reverse connection can't be established. How can I make the command keep retrying when ssh outputs   ssh: Remote TCP forward request failed (port 10000 -> localhost:22) your method works but it will still establish connect and stop trying until next loss. I know tha if I try to connect reverse and it fails the router will close port and the tunnel will reestablish but not if the ssh connection is already started because script.

Comment: So basically I need until ssh runs and doesn't output ssh: Remote TCP forward request failed (port 10000 -> localhost:22) keep running command